# Setting symbology type and color based on data using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have a point vector layer with several attributes in QGIS Dufour. 
One of them is satellite name, and the other is date. I want to display different dates with different colors (using some gradient) while the satellite name rules the type of symbol.
For example GOES-13 is a square, AQUA a dot, TERRA a triangle.

Satellite  date

goes-13   01/01/2014

goes-13   01/01/2014

aqua      01/01/2014

aqua      01/01/2014

terra     02/01/2014

... and so on

I know how to change the size or rotation of the symbol, but not the type.

[image: This is what I got]

the solution

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1) I've built a set of data based your requirements:

[image]

2) I have set an expression for displaying the label alternatively as **name** or **date**:
[image]

3) I've prepared the rules for the styles:
[image]

Please, notice that the in defining the rules for displaying different dates, I've used a color ramp based on a gradient:

[image]
[image]

4) And finally, here's what I've obtained:
[image]

Is this what you are looking for?