# Rule Based styling with different forms and colors

Tags: qgis, symbology, rule-based

I have a map about different locations of amphibians. I want that the colors illustrates the specific species and the form illustrates the stadium (young, adult). I know how to give different colors according to the species, but I didn't managed to also add different forms.

The problem is similar to the following one [Setting symbology type and color based on data using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83620/setting-symbology-type-and-color-based-on-data-using-qgis) but the answer there didn't helped me. I think it works by using rule based symbology, but I didn't managed to find out how I have to set my rules.

Comment: When creating rules, you may refine those, e.g. based on categories. The corresponding button is at the bottom left, below the plus and minus symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this expression

```sql
CASE
   WHEN "id" IN (1,2,3,4,5) THEN 'circle'
   WHEN "id" IN (6,7,8,9,10) THEN 'square'
   ELSE 'triangle'
END
```

in the `"Expression String Builder"`, see image below

[image: example]

*Note:* When hovering at each symbol you can see the default name of it.

For colours check this thread [Multiple styles in one layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363125/multiple-styles-in-one-layer-in-qgis).

Comment: Thank you very much it worked out. But now I have the problem that I want to create a map and when I add the legend it only adds the layer as one and not the single expressions (e.g. Square = Frog). Do you got a solution for this problem?

Comment: This is a small disadvantage of this approach =)

Comment: So its not possbile? Do you maybe know a diffrent approach where it is also possible to generate legend entries?

Comment: I suggest you asking it as a new question

Comment: Alright I will do that, thanks alot for your help!