# Styling lines depending on several attributes

Tags: qgis, line, style

I have a line shape file which I made from DWG file. I have several fields which I want to use for styling. I have colour, width and type. I need to specify colour, width and type independantly.

For example colour=1, width=2 and type="dashed line" or colour=3, width=1 and type="continious line". Colours are not range or random colours, they should be specified manually 1 is red, 2 - is yellow etc. The same with line types. Width can be either range, or specified manually as well as colour and width.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: You need to study case/when statements

Comment: Well, I tried to use rules for styles. And I can for exmple make a rule: field1 = 1 = red colour. field1 = 2 = yellow colour. And the same for each value. The same thing I can do for width or line type, But I don't know how to combine it all together in that case

Comment: I also tried to use "simple symbol" - there you can adjust values separatly for colour, width and type but I anly can specify range or a single value, not a specific value

Comment: Check these threads also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373642/rule-based-styling-with-different-forms-and-colors and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83620/setting-symbology-type-and-color-based-on-data-using-qgis

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I need.